# When converting polar to cartesian, a slice of the pie is missing

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook, contourf

I have done measurements on external software where I do my measurements in the cylindrical coordinates R, phi and z. However, I select one z, to make a contourplot over so I have coordinates in R and phi. To turn that into x and y, I make a 2D array of x and y with x being equal to R * cos(phi) and y to R * sin(phi). Like this:

```
t_xray = np.zeros((Rbins, Phibins))
t_yray = np.zeros((Rbins, Phibins))

for i in range(0, Rbins):
    for j in range(0, Phibins):
        t_xray[i,j] = Rray[i] * np.cos(Phiray[j])
        t_yray[i,j] = Rray[i] * np.sin(Phiray[j])
```

with Rbins and Phibins being equal to the length of the arrays of R's and phi's. Seems like a legitimate way to get it done, right? Apparently not, as this is what my plot looks like:
[Plot with slice of the pie missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8VcI.jpg). Made possible with:

```
plt.contourf(t_xray, t_yray, Doos_TG43, 1000, locator = ticker.LogLocator())
cbar = plt.colorbar(label = r'$\it{D}$ (cGy$\cdot$ h$^{-1}$)')
```

My first thought was that there was somehow a bigger leap in-between two angles that Python couldn't interpolate in-between, but when printing the array of phi's, you can see the leap between the first and last angle in the array is the same as in-between any element of the array (assuming we count k2pi + phi as phi):

```
[0.03141593 0.09424778 0.15707963 0.21991149 0.28274334 0.34557519
 0.40840704 0.4712389  0.53407075 0.5969026  0.65973446 0.72256631
 0.78539816 0.84823002 0.91106187 0.97389372 1.03672558 1.09955743
 1.16238928 1.22522113 1.28805299 1.35088484 1.41371669 1.47654855
 1.5393804  1.60221225 1.66504411 1.72787596 1.79070781 1.85353967
 1.91637152 1.97920337 2.04203522 2.10486708 2.16769893 2.23053078
 2.29336264 2.35619449 2.41902634 2.4818582  2.54469005 2.6075219
 2.67035376 2.73318561 2.79601746 2.85884931 2.92168117 2.98451302
 3.04734487 3.11017673 3.17300858 3.23584043 3.29867229 3.36150414
 3.42433599 3.48716785 3.5499997  3.61283155 3.6756634  3.73849526
 3.80132711 3.86415896 3.92699082 3.98982267 4.05265452 4.11548638
 4.17831823 4.24115008 4.30398194 4.36681379 4.42964564 4.49247749
 4.55530935 4.6181412  4.68097305 4.74380491 4.80663676 4.86946861
 4.93230047 4.99513232 5.05796417 5.12079603 5.18362788 5.24645973
 5.30929158 5.37212344 5.43495529 5.49778714 5.560619   5.62345085
 5.6862827  5.74911456 5.81194641 5.87477826 5.93761012 6.00044197
 6.06327382 6.12610567 6.18893753 6.25176938]
```

So it seems I am completely out of the loop here. Why is it as if a slice is cut from the 'pie', despite everything I just mentioned?

To summarise, I tried to see whether the problem is something with the angles, but it turns out even that doesn't help giving back the slice. I have no idea what cause a piece to go missing suddenly.

Comment: Presumably you need to repeat the first angle at the end of the array to get a "closed curve".

Comment: This was it. Didn't know how I was going to even do this, but I figured it out. Thanks